# Cells disappearing in static table when working with keyboard before displaying whole table

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, xcode-storyboard

I have created one larger static table using a storyboard (can't fit to an iPhone 6 display). [Static table in the storyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NJ3d.png)

It is displayed correctly only when I scroll all the way through the table. Problem occurs when I open any keyboard before scrolling through the table [(keyboard editing text field)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laKMG.png), than some of my cells disappear.
 [Cells disappeared.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXl1r.png) They appear only when I scroll back up and down again.

Any suggestions on what is wrong?

[UDPATE]
I tried to recreate the problem and it appears that the problem is caused by constraints. When I add classic UITextField it works just fine, but when I add ANY constraints, it behaves exactly like described above.

Comment: Try to move the window up, when you show the keyboard,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this problem is to call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` on every disappearing cell everytime `UITextField Editing Did End`.

```
// example code
@IBAction func textFieldEndEditing(_ sender: UITextField) {
    for cell in brokenConstraintsCells {
        cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }
}
```